# Can Velocity or Freemarker template be used for VIEW of Custom plugin portlet?

Tags: templates, liferay, portlet, liferay-velocity

I am trying to have a custom plugin portlet in liferay for which I can customize the view page with velocity or free-marker template like we have for Asset Publisher in Liferay 6.2.

#### Requirement

I have a screen for admin (CRUD) through which data would be added in my custom tables through this portlet and then there is a VIEW page for all other users.

Now this portlet can be deployed on different sites or different pages with page-scope and the requirement is that it should have a different look & feel for different pages. Currently we are handling this scenario through deploying different themes to configure the look & Feel of the portlet, but we also need some layout changes which is a limitation with themes.

So I was thinking if we can utilize something similar to a velocity template for the View page but I am not sure where to start and whether liferay provides some easy way to do this. So that we create a template and upload it in the configuration and the VIEW page UI is changed.

I would be grateful if there are some pointers to help me in this direction or atleast can say about the feasibility part of it or an alternative.

Thanks

**Environment:** Liferay 6.2 GA1

Comment: Use ADT framework: https://www.liferay.com/it/web/eduardo.garcia/blog/-/blogs/new-ways-of-customization-with-application-display-templates-part-ii-

Comment: Will try that out and let you know. That seems to be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: did you try out ADT? I think that is the proper solution but can you give some details about it? Thanks